# How to write OSX/Finder tags as metadata into PDF?

Tags: macos, pdf, finder, metadata, tags

I have added tags to all of my PDF documents, but the problem is, that these kind of tags are only supported by OSX (Mavericks), that means they are gone if I want to use the PDF on a e.g. windows or linux machine.

I'am looking for a solution to **automatically** write all my tags into the PDF as keyword metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start: [Tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) is a command line tool to manipulate tags in Mavericks.
[ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is a command line tool for writing metadata into images. 
So you need to do something like this to glue them together in a command line function:

```
function tags2metadata(){ 
   tags=$(tag -N "$1");                
   exiftool -Keywords="${tags//,/, }" "$1";
   tag --add "$tags" "$1";
}
```

`tags=$(tag -N "$1");` harvests the tags as a comma separated list (the -N option is to avoid it displaying the file name in its output), eg `good,bad,ugly`

`exiftool -Keywords="${tags//,/, }" "$1";` adds the tags to the ["Keyword"](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/PDF.html#Info) metadata field in the pdf metadata (the expression `${tags//,/, }` [replaces](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) every comma in `$tags` with comma+space, so that they become separate keywords).

Now exiftool creates a new file with the name of the original file and renames the original; eg. foo.pdf is renamed to foo.pdf_original and a new file foo.pdf is created with the modified metadata. You can change this by adding `-overwrite_original` to the exiftool command like this:

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -Keywords="${tags//,/, }" "$1";
```

but I chose to just re-write the mavericks Finder tags to the new file using `tag --add "$tags" "$1";` ($1 in a function stands for the input it is given).

So to use it, you could then open a terminal, type in the script above, `cd` to the directory with your pdfs in it and do:

```
for i in *.pdf
   do tags2metadata "$i"
done
```

If you open the new file and check for keywords, you should find all your Finder tags in there.

To install tags and exiftool I recommend [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Once you've installed it you just need to type `brew install exiftool tag` and it will do the necessary magic for you.

**Please** test this on files that you don't mind screwing up before you let it loose on your good stuff.